# How do I change the background image of the main menu?

Tags: starcraft-2

On many live streams (recently Cella), I have seen that people have changed their background image on the multiplayer menu screen. Honestly, I am getting a bit sick of that ugly guy's closeup scarred face.

How does one configure this?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot / link to look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a pretty detailed guide on exactly how to do this, including screenshots and video tutorials.

http://elusive-teliko.blogspot.com/2011/04/customise-background-images.html

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tried it, but one way to do it should be the following:

- Get a program that can read and write `.mpq` files, which Blizzard uses to store game resources. For example this [MPQ editor](http://www.zezula.net/en/mpq/download.html).
- Make a backup of your `Starcraft II/Battle.net/Battle.net.MPQ` file.
- Open the `Starcraft II/Battle.net/Battle.net.MPQ` file in the editor.
- In `Battle.net/Shared` in this file you see lots of `.dds` files with cryptic names. These are the images displayed in the game client.
- Extract these `.dds` files.
- Get a program that can display and encode `.dds` files, for example [ATI's The Compressonator](http://developer.amd.com/gpu/compressonator/pages/default.aspx)
- Find the image you want to replace. If you are searching for a background image I would recommend to to start with the largest files. Maybe there are also thumbnail programs out there that support `.dds` which could be useful to find what you are searching for.
- Encode your own picture as `.dds` and give it the same name as the one you want to replace.
- Replace the original picture with your newly encoded one in the `.mpq` file.

With this modified `.mpq` file, Starcraft should display your modified picture.

Note that you are probably not allowed to modify game files. It could be considered hacking and might get your account banned, or it might interfere with future upgrades. I don't recommend that you do this.

Comment: Good info - this is of course a possibility, but I really do not think pros would be doing things to violate the terms of use on a live stream, so I believe there must be a legit way of accomplishing this.

Comment: @tenfour: Maybe you could also pack the replacement picture in it's own mod and use that to override the default, but I have no idea about modding SC2 and can't say if or how that would work. The above description was the most straight forward way I could come up with, I'm sure it can be refined with some effort.