# Is there a way to change the Raynor loading screen in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm getting tired of seeing Jim Raynor's face every time I launch Starcraft 2.  Is there a way to change the image without violating the games EULA?  If so, is there a website that has preconfigured images we can use?

[image: It sure is hot in this suit!]

Comment: Keep in mind: every modification of game files violates the EULA and can result in a permanent banned account!

Comment: @F.S. That's  good point. In fact, I removed the mod tag from your question cowgod. I don't think we should be providing answers which would violate the games EULA, which a mod would do. I've also edited your question to make it clear that answers violating the EULA should not be posted.

Comment: Are you asking this? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18013/how-do-i-change-the-background-image-of-the-main-menu

Comment: @JuanManuel Nope, those are different backgrounds. One's effectively the log-in screen, and the other is the Logged-In screen. Admittedly, both are handled in the answer to that other question, but that doesn't mean this question is a duplicate of the other.

Comment: So, how many people are planning to buy Diablo III after seeing the EULA restrictions in StarCraft II?  Vote with your wallet, folks.

Comment: Not to worry, you've only got a few more months to wait til HotS changes your loading page.

Comment: FYI, the link posted by Teliko in the [previously linked question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18013/how-do-i-change-the-background-image-of-the-main-menu) has information on how to change the loading screen picture. Just search for "Jim Raynor" in the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace the image you would need to modify the game files, [just like when you want to replace any other images](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18013/how-do-i-change-the-background-image-of-the-main-menu).

The picture you are looking for is `Assets\Textures\startupimage.dds` in the `Starcraft II\Mods\Core.SC2Mod\base.SC2Assets.mpq` file. Modifying this file is probably against the EULA and can cause all kinds of trouble, so it's recommended to keep on looking at Raynor while the game loads.